# How to avoid the menu button showing up in place of the horizontal navigation bar on the Google Site mobile version?

Tags: google-classic-sites

When I open [my Google site](http://www.shaneauerbach.com) on my phone, it replaces the horizontal navigation bar with a menu button. When I click on the menu button, it does show the horizontal navigation bar. The problem is the menu button really serves no purpose in my case as the horizontal navigation bar takes up no more vertical space than the menu button! How can I get rid of the menu button and just show the horizontal navigation bar at all times?

Here's a picture of the menu button, first pre-click and then post-click:

[image: pre-click google site menu bar]

[image: post-click google site menu bar]

Note that I can get rid of the menu bar by unchecking "Automatically adjust site to mobile phones," but I generally like what that button is doing but for this one feature.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to hide the menu button with the "Automatically adjust site..." setting turned on. Have you tried the new Google Sites?

Comment: @Rubén I would like to, but I'm not going to manually copy and paste my entire site over (which is their current best effort at migration--see https://support.google.com/sites/answer/7035197?hl=en). I suspect you're right that this problem may not be relevant with the new sites...